# how to move side menu with jquery along with top bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]

How can I make the side menu which is on the right scroll down when the bookmark bar gets to it, and then move along with the bookmark bar with jquery, and not knowing that menu is moving, it's like it stood stay still.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to:

- Watch the `$(window).scroll` event
- Check if the users `scrollTop` at the sidebars `.offset().top`
- If so, set the side to `position: fixed`
- Otherwise, restore it to `position: relative`